# How can I get grep to care about the order of characters in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to have R search through the column iphod$a and return strings that have "1" and then "0". It should thus return things like "A1.P.E0.L" or like "B.O1.I0" -- anything that has a "1" and then a "0". I currently have this code:

```
grep("(?=.*1)(?=.*0)", iphod$a)
```

However, this returns anything with a "1" and a "0" but in any order (e.g., "A0.P.E1.L". How do I get this to care about the order these characters are in?

Thanks!

Comment: `grep("1.*0", iphod$a)`

Comment: @Psidom OP not clear on what to do with `> grep("1.*0", "A0.P1.E0.")
[1] 1`. There's definitely a `1` before a `0` so should this one return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex like `[^0]*1.*0.*` will do here.

e.g.

```
> grep("[^0]*1.*0.*", "A1.P.E0.")
[1] 1
```